# was 8.5 - how to invoke remote ejb3 between servers

Tags: websphere

I have two WAS 8.5 servers running.
In server A I have an ear file with EJB3 beans.
If I'm doing local lookups on server A I'm getting the bean and all works fine.

What I'm trying to do is to invoke the EJB3 beans from the other server.
Server B has this code:

```
final Hashtable props = new Hashtable();
props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "corbaloc:iiop:172.17.2.197:2809"); //172.17.2.197 is the ip of server A
final Context ctx = new javax.naming.InitialContext(props);
Object homeObject = ctx.lookup("java:global/myApp/test-ejb3/EJB3StatelessSessionBean!com.app.test.ejb3.EJB3SessionBeanRemote");
```

This throw an exception:

```
2012-11-22 14:52:50,438 INFO  [WebContainer : 48](com.app.test.ejb3tasks.EJB3ClientTask) - Failed to invoke EJB through WLstatelessRemoteEJB3TaskSessionBean interface.
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Context: Config71154VM0Node01Cell/applications, name: myApp/test-ejb3/EJB3StatelessSessionBean!com.app.test.ejb3.EJB3SessionBeanRemote: First component in name EJB3StatelessSessionBean!com.app.test.ejb3.EJB3SessionBeanRemote not found. [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]
at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.mapNotFoundException(CNContextImpl.java:4563)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1821)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1776)
...
Caused by: 
org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0
at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipcos.WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.do_resolve_complete_info(WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.java:568)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.resolve_complete_info(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:2169)
at com.ibm.WsnOptimizedNaming._NamingContextStub.resolve_complete_info(_NamingContextStub.java:538)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl$2.run(CNContextImpl.java:2957)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl$2.run(CNContextImpl.java:2953)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.CommonHelpers.retry(CommonHelpers.java:801)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.cosResolve(CNContextImpl.java:2951)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1817)
... 40 more
```

Server A (the target server) dumpNameSpace:

```
    32 (top)/applications/com.ibm.ws.AppNameSpaces/myApp
       32                                                    javax.naming.Context
       33 (top)/applications/com.ibm.ws.AppNameSpaces/myApp/root
       33                                                    javax.naming.Context
       34 (top)/applications/com.ibm.ws.AppNameSpaces/myApp/root/AppName
       34                                                    java.lang.String
       35 (top)/applications/com.ibm.ws.AppNameSpaces/myApp/root/test-ejb3
       35                                                    javax.naming.Context
       36 [Binding name not available.]                      [Class name not available.]
       36    ERROR: Received the following naming exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Unexpected exception occurred. [Root exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError]
       37 [Binding name not available.]                      [Class name not available.]
       37    ERROR: Received the following naming exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Unexpected exception occurred. [Root exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError]
       38 (top)/applications/com.ibm.ws.AppNameSpaces/myApp/root/test-ejb3/EJB3StatefulSessionBean!com.app.test.ejb3.EJB3SessionBeanRemote
       38                                                    com.app.test.ejb3.EJB3SessionBeanRemote
       39 (top)/applications/com.ibm.ws.AppNameSpaces/myApp/root/test-ejb3/EJB3StatelessSessionBean!com.app.test.ejb3.EJB3SessionBeanRemote
       39                                                    com.app.test.ejb3.EJB3SessionBeanRemote
       40 (top)/applications/com.ibm.ws.AppNameSpaces/myApp/root/simulation-ng-business-2.5.9
       40                                                    javax.naming.Context
       41 (top)/applications/com.ibm.ws.AppNameSpaces/myApp/root/simulation-ng-business-2.5.9/SimpleSession!com.app.test.ejb.session.SimpleSessionHome
       41                                                    com.app.test.ejb.session.SimpleSessionHome
       42 [Binding name not available.]                      [Class name not available.]
       42    ERROR: Received the following naming exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Unexpected exception occurred. [Root exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError]
       43 [Binding name not available.]                      [Class name not available.]
       43    ERROR: Received the following naming exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Unexpected exception occurred. [Root exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError]
       44 [Binding name not available.]                      [Class name not available.]
       44    ERROR: Received the following naming exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Unexpected exception occurred. [Root exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError]
       45 [Binding name not available.]                      [Class name not available.]
       45    ERROR: Received the following naming exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Unexpected exception occurred. [Root exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError]
       46 (top)/applications/com.ibm.ws.AppNameSpaces/myApp/root/simulation-ng-business-2.5.9/SessionAnyTask!com.app.test.ejb.session.SessionAnyTaskHome
       46                                                    com.app.test.ejb.session.SessionAnyTaskHome
       47 (top)/applications/com.ibm.ws.AppNameSpaces/myApp/root/simulation-ng-business-2.5.9/SessionStateful!com.app.test.ejb.session.SessionStatefulHome
       47                                                    com.app.test.ejb.session.SessionStatefulHome
       48 [Binding name not available.]                      [Class name not available.]
       48    ERROR: Received the following naming exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Unexpected exception occurred. [Root exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError]
       49 (top)/applications/com.ibm.ws.AppNameSpaces/myApp/root/simulation-ng-business-2.5.9/SessionJDBC!com.app.test.ejb.session.SessionJDBCHome
       49                                                    com.app.test.ejb.session.SessionJDBCHome
       50 (top)/applications/com.ibm.ws.AppNameSpaces/myApp/root/simulation-ng-business-2.5.9/JDBCDirect!com.app.test.ejb.session.JDBCDirectHome
       50                                                    com.app.test.ejb.session.JDBCDirectHome
       51 (top)/applications/com.ibm.ws.AppNameSpaces/isclite
       51                                                    javax.naming.Context
       52 (top)/applications/com.ibm.ws.AppNameSpaces/isclite/root
       52                                                    javax.naming.Context
       53 (top)/applications/com.ibm.ws.AppNameSpaces/isclite/root/AppName
       53                                                    java.lang.String
       61 (top)/applications/com.ibm.ws.AppNameSpaces/ibmasyncrsp/root
       61                                                    javax.naming.Context
       62 (top)/applications/com.ibm.ws.AppNameSpaces/ibmasyncrsp/root/AppName
       62                                                    java.lang.String
       63 (top)/applications/com.ibm.ws.AppNameSpaces/filetransferSecured
       63                                                    javax.naming.Context
       64 (top)/applications/com.ibm.ws.AppNameSpaces/filetransferSecured/root
       64                                                    javax.naming.Context
       65 (top)/applications/com.ibm.ws.AppNameSpaces/filetransferSecured/root/AppName
       65                                                    java.lang.String
       66 (top)/applications/cell                            javax.naming.Context
       66    Linked to context: Config71154VM0Node01Cell
       67 (top)/applications/myApp                   javax.naming.Context
       68 (top)/applications/myApp/simulation-ng-business-2.5.9
       68                                                    javax.naming.Context
       69 [Binding name not available.]                      [Class name not available.]
       69    ERROR: Received the following naming exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Unexpected exception occurred. [Root exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError]
       70 (top)/applications/myApp/simulation-ng-business-2.5.9/JDBCDirect!com.app.test.ejb.session.JDBCDirectHome
       70                                                    com.app.test.ejb.session.JDBCDirectHome
       71 [Binding name not available.]                      [Class name not available.]
       71    ERROR: Received the following naming exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Unexpected exception occurred. [Root exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError]
       72 [Binding name not available.]                      [Class name not available.]
       72    ERROR: Received the following naming exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Unexpected exception occurred. [Root exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError]
       73 [Binding name not available.]                      [Class name not available.]
       73    ERROR: Received the following naming exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Unexpected exception occurred. [Root exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError]
       74 (top)/applications/myApp/simulation-ng-business-2.5.9/SessionStateful!com.app.test.ejb.session.SessionStatefulHome
       74                                                    com.app.test.ejb.session.SessionStatefulHome
       75 [Binding name not available.]                      [Class name not available.]
       75    ERROR: Received the following naming exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Unexpected exception occurred. [Root exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError]
       76 (top)/applications/myApp/simulation-ng-business-2.5.9/SessionJDBC!com.app.test.ejb.session.SessionJDBCHome
       76                                                    com.app.test.ejb.session.SessionJDBCHome
       77 (top)/applications/myApp/simulation-ng-business-2.5.9/SessionAnyTask!com.app.test.ejb.session.SessionAnyTaskHome
       77                                                    com.app.test.ejb.session.SessionAnyTaskHome
       78 (top)/applications/myApp/simulation-ng-business-2.5.9/SimpleSession!com.app.test.ejb.session.SimpleSessionHome
       78                                                    com.app.test.ejb.session.SimpleSessionHome
       79 (top)/applications/myApp/test-ejb3
       79                                                    javax.naming.Context
       80 (top)/applications/myApp/test-ejb3/EJB3StatelessSessionBean!com.app.test.ejb3.EJB3SessionBeanRemote
       80                                                    com.app.test.ejb3.EJB3SessionBeanRemote
       81 [Binding name not available.]                      [Class name not available.]
       81    ERROR: Received the following naming exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Unexpected exception occurred. [Root exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError]
       82 [Binding name not available.]                      [Class name not available.]
       82    ERROR: Received the following naming exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Unexpected exception occurred. [Root exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError]
       83 (top)/applications/myApp/test-ejb3/EJB3StatefulSessionBean!com.app.test.ejb3.EJB3SessionBeanRemote
       83                                                    com.app.test.ejb3.EJB3SessionBeanRemote
       84 (top)/applications/SchedulerCalendars              javax.naming.Context
       85 (top)/applications/SchedulerCalendars/Calendars    javax.naming.Context
       86 (top)/applications/SchedulerCalendars/Calendars/DefaultUserCalendar!com.ibm.websphere.scheduler.UserCalendarHome
       86                                                    com.ibm.websphere.scheduler.UserCalendarHome
       87 (top)/applications/SchedulerCalendars/Calendars/DefaultUserCalendar
       87                                                    com.ibm.websphere.scheduler.UserCalendarHome
       88 (top)/applications/query                           javax.naming.Context
       89 (top)/applications/query/querybean                 javax.naming.Context
       90 [Binding name not available.]                      [Class name not available.]
       90    ERROR: Received the following naming exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Unexpected exception occurred. [Root exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError]
       91 (top)/applications/query/querybean/Query!com.ibm.websphere.ejbquery.QueryHome
       91                                                    com.ibm.websphere.ejbquery.QueryHome
       92 (top)/applications/DefaultApplication              javax.naming.Context
       93 (top)/applications/DefaultApplication/Increment    javax.naming.Context
       94 (top)/applications/ManagementEJB                   javax.naming.Context
       95 (top)/applications/ManagementEJB/mejb              javax.naming.Context
       96 (top)/applications/ManagementEJB/mejb/Management   javax.management.j2ee.ManagementHome
       97 (top)/applications/ManagementEJB/mejb/Management!javax.management.j2ee.ManagementHome
       97                                                    javax.management.j2ee.ManagementHome
       98 (top)/persistent                                   javax.naming.Context
       99 (top)/persistent/cell                              javax.naming.Context
       99    Linked to context: Config71154VM0Node01Cell
      128 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/com/ibm/websphere/ejbquery
      128                                                    javax.naming.Context
      129 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/com/ibm/websphere/ejbquery/Query
      129                                                    com.ibm.websphere.ejbquery.QueryHome
      130 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/cell
      130                                                    javax.naming.Context
      130    Linked to context: Config71154VM0Node01Cell
      131 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/jdbc
      131                                                    javax.naming.Context
      132 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/jdbc/DefaultEJBTimerDataSource
      132                                                    javax.resource.cci.ConnectionFactory
      133 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/wm
      133                                                    javax.naming.Context
      134 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/wm/default
      134                                                    com.ibm.websphere.asynchbeans.WorkManager
      135 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/wm/ard
      135                                                    com.ibm.websphere.asynchbeans.WorkManager
      136 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/jta
      136                                                    javax.naming.Context
      137 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/jta/usertransaction
      137                                                    java.lang.Object
      138 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/UserRegistry
      138                                                    com.ibm.websphere.security._UserRegistry_Stub
      139 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer
      139                                                    javax.naming.Context
      140 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer/ManagementEJB
      140                                                    javax.naming.Context
      141 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer/ManagementEJB/mejb.jar
      141                                                    javax.naming.Context
      142 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer/ManagementEJB/mejb.jar/EJBFactory
      142                                                    com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer.EJBFactory
      143 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer/ManagementEJB/EJBFactory
      143                                                    com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer.EJBFactory
      144 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer/DefaultApplication
      144                                                    javax.naming.Context
      145 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer/DefaultApplication/Increment.jar
      145                                                    javax.naming.Context
      146 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer/DefaultApplication/Increment.jar/EJBFactory
      146                                                    com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer.EJBFactory
      147 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer/DefaultApplication/EJBFactory
      147                                                    com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer.EJBFactory
      148 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer/SchedulerCalendars
      148                                                    javax.naming.Context
      149 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer/SchedulerCalendars/Calendars.jar
      149                                                    javax.naming.Context
      150 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer/SchedulerCalendars/Calendars.jar/EJBFactory
      150                                                    com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer.EJBFactory
      151 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer/SchedulerCalendars/EJBFactory
      151                                                    com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer.EJBFactory
      152 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer/myApp
      152                                                    javax.naming.Context
      153 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer/myApp/EJBFactory
      153                                                    com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer.EJBFactory
      154 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer/myApp/ejb
      154                                                    javax.naming.Context
      155 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer/myApp/ejb/simulation-ng-business-2.5.9.jar
      155                                                    javax.naming.Context
      156 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer/myApp/ejb/simulation-ng-business-2.5.9.jar/EJBFactory
      156                                                    com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer.EJBFactory
      157 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer/myApp/ejb/test-ejb3.jar
      157                                                    javax.naming.Context
      158 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer/myApp/ejb/test-ejb3.jar/EJBFactory
      158                                                    com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer.EJBFactory
      159 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer/ivtApp
      159                                                    javax.naming.Context
      160 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer/ivtApp/ivtEJB.jar
      160                                                    javax.naming.Context
      161 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer/ivtApp/ivtEJB.jar/EJBFactory
      161                                                    com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer.EJBFactory
      162 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer/ivtApp/EJBFactory
      162                                                    com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer.EJBFactory
      163 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer/query
      163                                                    javax.naming.Context
      164 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer/query/EJBFactory
      164                                                    com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer.EJBFactory
      165 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer/query/querybean.jar
      165                                                    javax.naming.Context
      166 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer/query/querybean.jar/EJBFactory
      166                                                    com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer.EJBFactory
      167 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/com.ibm.isc
      167                                                    javax.naming.Context
      168 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/com.ibm.isc/PluginRegistry
      168                                                    javax.naming.Context
      169 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/com.ibm.isc/PluginRegistry/Config71154VM0Node01
      169                                                    com.ibm.ws.PluginRegistry
      170 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/ejb
      170                                                    javax.naming.Context
      171 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/ejb/mgmt
      171                                                    javax.naming.Context
      172 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/ejb/mgmt/MEJB
      172                                                    javax.management.j2ee.ManagementHome
      173 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/ejb/ivtEJBObject
      173                                                    com.ibm.websphere.ivt.ivtEJB.ivtEJBHome
      174 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/ejb/myApp
      174                                                    javax.naming.Context
      175 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/ejb/myApp/ejb
      175                                                    javax.naming.Context
      176 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/ejb/myApp/ejb/test-ejb3.jar
      176                                                    javax.naming.Context
      177 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/ejb/myApp/ejb/test-ejb3.jar/EJB3StatelessSessionBean#com.app.test.ejb3.EJB3SessionBeanRemote
      177                                                    com.app.test.ejb3.EJB3SessionBeanRemote
      178 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/ejb/myApp/ejb/test-ejb3.jar/EJB3StatefulSessionBean#com.app.test.ejb3.EJB3SessionBeanRemote
      178                                                    com.app.test.ejb3.EJB3SessionBeanRemote
      179 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/servername
      179                                                    java.lang.String
      180 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/SecurityServer
      180                                                    com.ibm.ws.security.server._SecurityServer_Stub
      181 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/com.app.test.ejb3.EJB3SessionBeanRemote
      181                                                    AmbiguousEJBReference
      182 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/simulation
      182                                                    javax.naming.Context
      183 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/simulation/ejb
      183                                                    javax.naming.Context
      184 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/simulation/ejb/SessionJDBC
      184                                                    com.app.test.ejb.session.SessionJDBCHome
      185 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/simulation/ejb/Account
      185                                                    com.app.test.ejb.entity.AccountHome
      186 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/simulation/ejb/SimpleSession
      186                                                    com.app.test.ejb.session.SimpleSessionHome
      187 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/simulation/ejb/SessionAnyTask
      187                                                    com.app.test.ejb.session.SessionAnyTaskHome
      188 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/simulation/ejb/JDBCDirect
      188                                                    com.app.test.ejb.session.JDBCDirectHome
      189 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/simulation/ejb/SessionStateful
      189                                                    com.app.test.ejb.session.SessionStatefulHome
      190 (top)/nodes/Config71154VM0Node01/servers/server1/simulation/ejb/Customer
      190                                                    com.app.test.ejb.entity.CustomerHome
```

```
cat SystemOut.log | grep CNTR0167I > /tmp/CNTR0167I.txt
[11/28/12 10:54:04:053 IST] 00000040 EJBContainerI I   CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.app.test.ejb3.EJB3SessionBeanRemote interface of the EJB3StatefulSessionBean enterprise bean in the ejb/test-ejb3.jar module of the myApp application.  The binding location is: ejb/myApp/ejb/test-ejb3.jar/EJB3StatefulSessionBean#com.app.test.ejb3.EJB3SessionBeanRemote
[11/28/12 10:54:04:055 IST] 00000040 EJBContainerI I   CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.app.test.ejb3.EJB3SessionBeanRemote interface of the EJB3StatefulSessionBean enterprise bean in the ejb/test-ejb3.jar module of the myApp application.  The binding location is: com.app.test.ejb3.EJB3SessionBeanRemote
[11/28/12 10:54:04:056 IST] 00000040 AbstractEJBRu I   CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.app.test.ejb3.EJB3SessionBeanRemote interface of the EJB3StatefulSessionBean enterprise bean in the ejb/test-ejb3.jar module of the myApp application.  The binding location is: java:global/myApp/test-ejb3/EJB3StatefulSessionBean!com.app.test.ejb3.EJB3SessionBeanRemote
[11/28/12 10:54:04:057 IST] 00000040 EJBContainerI I   CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.app.test.ejb3.EJB3SessionBeanLocal interface of the EJB3StatefulSessionBean enterprise bean in the ejb/test-ejb3.jar module of the myApp application.  The binding location is: ejblocal:myApp/ejb/test-ejb3.jar/EJB3StatefulSessionBean#com.app.test.ejb3.EJB3SessionBeanLocal
[11/28/12 10:54:04:058 IST] 00000040 EJBContainerI I   CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.app.test.ejb3.EJB3SessionBeanLocal interface of the EJB3StatefulSessionBean enterprise bean in the ejb/test-ejb3.jar module of the myApp application.  The binding location is: ejblocal:com.app.test.ejb3.EJB3SessionBeanLocal
[11/28/12 10:54:04:058 IST] 00000040 AbstractEJBRu I   CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.app.test.ejb3.EJB3SessionBeanLocal interface of the EJB3StatefulSessionBean enterprise bean in the ejb/test-ejb3.jar module of the myApp application.  The binding location is: java:global/myApp/test-ejb3/EJB3StatefulSessionBean!com.app.test.ejb3.EJB3SessionBeanLocal
[11/28/12 10:54:04:064 IST] 00000040 EJBContainerI I   CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.app.test.ejb3.EJB3SessionBeanRemote interface of the EJB3StatelessSessionBean enterprise bean in the ejb/test-ejb3.jar module of the myApp application.  The binding location is: ejb/myApp/ejb/test-ejb3.jar/EJB3StatelessSessionBean#com.app.test.ejb3.EJB3SessionBeanRemote
[11/28/12 10:54:04:065 IST] 00000040 AbstractEJBRu I   CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.app.test.ejb3.EJB3SessionBeanRemote interface of the EJB3StatelessSessionBean enterprise bean in the ejb/test-ejb3.jar module of the myApp application.  The binding location is: java:global/myApp/test-ejb3/EJB3StatelessSessionBean!com.app.test.ejb3.EJB3SessionBeanRemote
[11/28/12 10:54:04:065 IST] 00000040 EJBContainerI I   CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.app.test.ejb3.EJB3SessionBeanLocal interface of the EJB3StatelessSessionBean enterprise bean in the ejb/test-ejb3.jar module of the myApp application.  The binding location is: ejblocal:myApp/ejb/test-ejb3.jar/EJB3StatelessSessionBean#com.app.test.ejb3.EJB3SessionBeanLocal
[11/28/12 10:54:04:066 IST] 00000040 AbstractEJBRu I   CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.app.test.ejb3.EJB3SessionBeanLocal interface of the EJB3StatelessSessionBean enterprise bean in the ejb/test-ejb3.jar module of the myApp application.  The binding location is: java:global/myApp/test-ejb3/EJB3StatelessSessionBean!com.app.test.ejb3.EJB3SessionBeanLocal
```

The same lookup on server A (with provider url: corbaloc:iiop:localhost:2809) works.
I also tried to do the lookup using "ejb/..." instead of "java:global/..."

Comment: Can you try just by using "com.app.test.ejb3.EJB3SessionBeanRemote" as jndi name instead of "java:global/myApp/test-ejb3/EJB3StatelessSessionBean!com.app.test.ejb3.EJB3SessionBeanRemote"?

Comment: @trikelef This throw the same exception.

Comment: What does the CNTR0167I message from the target server say the java:global is for the target EJB?  What does PROFILE_HOME/bin/dumpNameSpace say for the target server?

Comment: @bkail - I edited the question with that details.

Comment: That's odd.  Perhaps you've encountered a product issue.  I would recommend opening a PMR with IBM.

Comment: no updates for this issue??